Routes of Vite React App served with Quarkus result in 404
I have create a Vite React app with:
npx create-vite my-app --template react

The app has some routes that are defined in the App.jsx
function App() {

  return (
   <Router>
    <Header/>
    {/* <TemporaryDrawer/> */}
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' Component={Home}/>
      <Route path='Home' Component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/regestrieren" Component={SignUp}/>
      <Route path="/anmelden" Component={SignIn}/>
      <Route path="/404" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />

      <Route path='Inventar' Component={Inventory}/>
      <Route path='Bestellungen' Component={Order}/>
      <Route path='Status' Component={State}/>
      <Route path='test' Component={SocketTest}/>
    </Routes>
    {/* <Footer/> */}
   </Router>
  )
}

export default App

i build the app with vite build which results in a dist folder that looks like this:
|-assets
  ->|index-D5iAeLHF.css
  ->|index-DFJTsdp1.js
|-images
|index.html

I coppied the content of the contents of the dist folder to:
src\main\resources\META-INF\resources 

in my Quarkus application as described here
When I am running the quarkus app in dev mode the correct index page of the vite + react web app is displayed, but all routs defined in App.jsx result in a 404 - Resource Not Found. Only the REST paths of the quakrus application work.
I tried creating a vite.config like this
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
   base: '/', // Set the base URL
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0', // Set the host
    port: 9001 // Set the port
  }
})

and add a root path and cros rules to the applications.properties in quarkus like this:
quarkus.http.port=9000
quarkus.http.root-path=/
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins = http://localhost:9001
quarkus.http.cors.headers = accept, origin, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.methods = GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS

But I can't get the other routs to load and don't know which part I messed up.
While searching, I came across guides like this which move npn and the js src into the quarkus workflow, which I don't want to use the extra dependencies at the moment.
Additional infos i missed when creating this question.

The whole app is bundeled into a docker containert.
The container is running behinde a nginx reverse proxy.


Does this answer your question? Quarkus - How to implement routing for Single Page Apps?

Unfortunately not. I added the NotFoundExceptionMapper into a new class and redeployed the app to "production" and the routing still does not work.
I added some details to the end of the question, regarding the whole setup.

I know you mentioned you didn't want to move npm into the Quarkus workflow, but I think you really will find setup easier, with less config, by using Quarkus Quinoa. https://quarkus.io/blog/quinoa-modern-ui-with-no-hassle/ introduces it, and the latest docs are here: https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-quinoa/dev/index.html
I have a feeling it might just fix the routing issues, and even if it doesn't, it will eliminate some other config and make live reload quite nice.

I spend the day restructuring my app to implement quinoa. The Paths are now found, but when trying to load them the request for the file is rejected with a 403:

Request URL: https://url/assets/index-B0f_eAc8.js
Referer: https://url/Inventar
Referrer Policy: Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

